# Can the Django urls.py system be turned into Pylon's Routes?

Tags: python, django, routes, pylons

Can the Django urls.py system be turned into Pylon's Routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you be  more specific?

If you want to adapt a django urlconf to routes at runtime it would be really tricky if not impossible and would require having a django settings.py present and an env variable pointing to it.

Otherwise translating a django urlconf to routes manually is doable. Routes is as flexible as django urlconfs when it comes to defining urlpatterns.